# Swapping nodes in double linked list in C

Tags: c, nodes, swap, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to swap nodes in a double linked list in C.

My list if as it follows: M4,M3,M2,M1.
I have a function that computes the dimension of the list and it reads it correctly as 4.

It all breaks down when I try to swap M3 with M2.(hoping to get after traversing it this: M4,M2,M3,M1.)

I use the following line in main: (prim is the the first node, M4)

```
swap_nodes1(prim->pNext, prim->pNext->pNext);
```

And the following code serves as my swapping function. (Note:i still need to cover the cases when switching the head with another node, or the tail with another node, yet I wanted first to swap some random middle positioned nodes.)

```
void swap_nodes1(pNODE object1, pNODE object2)
{
pNODE temp1,temp2;
temp1->pPrec=object1->pPrec;
temp1->pNext=object1->pNext;

object1->pPrec=object2->pPrec;
object1->pNext=object2->pNext;
object2->pPrec=temp1->pPrec;
object2->pNext=temp1->pNext;

free(temp1);
}
```

When I traverse the list for the 2nd time,i get: M4,M3,M1. Also the dim of the list is now 3 instead of 4,M2 magically disappearing.

Can anyone provide me an explanation on why I am getting this and what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a piece op paper and a pencil and do some drawing. There are 6 or 8 pointers involved; you only change 4.

Comment: I did take a piece of paper and a pencil aswell and thought it through. I am pretty sure that I need another 2 pointers for that I lose the prev and next connections of object1. If I am wrong, I would gladly accept the better solution,which  is really missing in your comment.

Comment: `temp1->pPrec`. That is dereferencing an uninitalised pointer. Which is Undefined Behaviour. That needs to be fixed before proceeding further with debugging.

Comment: There are as many as **eight** pointers involved in swapping dbl-linked list nodes, the most involved case when the nodes are (a) not adjacent, and (b) not on either end of the list. If they are adjacent it goes down to six, and potentially as few as four in the trivial case where they are adjacent *and* the only two nodes in the list. You're not going to do this right until the pointers pointing to your nodes (not just their values, the actual pointer variables) are involved as well. Of course you could always just swap the data value fields and leave the pointers as-is, but what fun is that?

Comment: Why are you `free()`ing something that was not `[m/c/re]alloc()`ed and may or may not be a pointer?

Comment: @EOF it is funny but without that line of freeing, the .exe goes 'stopped working' and crashes.

Comment: @CatalinGhita Post a [MCVE].

Comment: Your program has multiple Undefined Behaviours such as dereferencing uninitialised pointers and freeing incorrect memory. There is no point speculating on the behavior of the program under those circumstances. Just fix those first, re-test and update your question with the results. Make sure you post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier if you draw it on paper and research it that way.

Assuming object1 and object2 are not NULL.

You need to think about the nodes that come before and after the two nodes you are swapping. The node just *before* your two swap nodes needs to point to object2 now instead of object1 (assuming that the node exists). And you need to make object2's preceding now point to the node just before your two swap nodes.

```
if ( object1->pPrec != NULL )
   object1->pPrec->pNext = object2;
object2->pPrec = object1->pPrec;
```

And you need to make object1's next points to the node just *after* your two swap nodes and that node needs to point back to object1 (if it exists).

```
object1->pNext = object2->pNext;
if ( object2->pNext != NULL ) 
    object2->pNext->pPrec = object1;
```

Then object1 needs to point back to object2 and object2 needs to point forward to object1.

```
object1->pPrec = object2;
object2->pNext = object1;
```

Comment: Your code only shows how to swap adjacent nodes, yet how can I swap random nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement doesn't specify what points to the first node of the list (M4), or if there is a pointer to the last node of the list (M1). It doesn't state if the list is circular, so I assume it's not circular.

When swapping nodes in a list, if the nodes to be swapped are adjacent (which is the example case, M3 and M2), then pointers need to be "rotated". If the nodes to be swapped are not adjacent, then pointers need to be swapped. The same logic can be used for both cases by first swapping what ever points to the two nodes, then swapping the two nodes pointers.

Using pointer to pointer to node will simplify the logic.